# Sum values of a column based on another boolean column, both true and false separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to find the existing answer for this, might have missed it. So this is part of my mysql table:

```
+-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+
| id  | is_actual | month      | sum    | sheet_id |
+-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+
| 243 |         1 | 2020-02-01 |      0 |        6 |
| 244 |         0 | 2020-02-01 | 100000 |        6 |
| 245 |         1 | 2020-05-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 246 |         1 | 2020-01-01 |    110 |        3 |
| 247 |         1 | 2020-07-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 248 |         1 | 2020-03-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 249 |         1 | 2020-08-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 250 |         1 | 2020-06-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 251 |         1 | 2020-02-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 252 |         1 | 2020-04-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 253 |         0 | 2020-05-01 |      0 |        3 |
| 254 |         0 | 2020-01-01 |      0 |        3 |
```

I would like to sum all amounts where is_actual is true and then all amounts where is_actual is false, in the same query, something like:

```
SUM(CASE `core_costsbudgetpermonth`.`is_actual` = 1 THEN `core_costsbudgetpermonth`.`sum` ELSE 0 END) AS sum_actual 
SUM(CASE `core_costsbudgetpermonth`.`is_actual` = 0 THEN `core_costsbudgetpermonth`.`sum` ELSE 0 END) AS sum_not_actual
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
This is my error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN `core_costsbudgetpermonth`.`sum` ELSE 0 END) FROM `core_costsbudgetpermonth' at line 1

Expected output something like:

```
+-------+---------+ 
+ 20833 | 130626  +
+-------+---------+
```

Comment: And, why is this not working? because your function seems to be correct

Comment: Please add expected output , why you think your code is wrong and the rest of the statement.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case WHEN ... and you need a comma after the first sum

review syntax here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need the case when

```
SUM(is_actual * sum) as sumactual,
-SUM((is_actual-1) * sum) as sumnotactual
```

You can utilise the boolean being 0 or 1 - multiplying sum and the bool together gives 0 when the bool is false and `sum` when it's true. If you subtract 1 from the bool it becomes 0 when it's true or -1 when it's false (then all you need to do is flip that negative `sum` around, or `(is_actual-1) * -sum` - so long as there's a double negative somewhere it works out )

You can even flip the boolean with NOT:

```
SUM(is_actual * sum) as sumactual,
SUM((NOT is_actual) * sum) as sumnotactual
```

---

By the way, CASE WHEN has two forms:

```
CASE 
  WHEN booleanTest THEN outputvalue 
 [WHEN otherBooleanTest THEN otherOutputValue ...] --as many WHENs as you like
 [ELSE elseValue] 
END

CASE variableName 
  WHEN variableValue THEN outputValue 
 [WHEN variableValue THEN outputValue ...] 
 [ELSE elseValue] 
END
```

And also because SUM ignores NULL (which is what CASE WHEN outputs when nothing matches) you don't need the ELSE 0 either. This means your `CASE WHEN` form can be reduced to variations like:

```
SUM(CASE is_actual WHEN true THEN sum END) as sumactual,
SUM(CASE is_actual WHEN false THEN sum END) as sumnotactual
```

Or

```
SUM(CASE WHEN is_actual THEN sum END) as sumactual,
SUM(CASE WHEN NOT is_actual THEN sum END) as sumnotactual
```

Comment: Added a bit to explain `case when` some more, in response to your question edit